# Postgres access via express.js is not working with Ubuntu environments variables

Tags: reactjs, postgresql, express, nginx

I have a PERN Stack that is not working due to the following 'error: password authentication failed for user "postgres"'.

In postgres (14.8) running on Ubuntu 22.04.2, I can log into postgres from either the (Ubuntu) users `ubuntu` or `postgres`, utilizing environment variables and peer authentication. Command `psql -d testdb` logs me in as ubuntu. With `printenv` I see:

```
PGPORT=5432
PGPASSWORD=password
PGUSER=ubuntu
PGDATABASE=testdb
PGHOST=localhost
```

So the above works fine, but my express.js app makes a request which results in 'error: password authentication failed for user "postgres"' and a Gateway timeout 504 in the browser.

Here is /etc/postgresql/14/main/pg_hba.conf:

```
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local   all             postgres                                peer

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     peer
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            scram-sha-256
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 scram-sha-256
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     peer
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            scram-sha-256
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 scram-sha-256
```

Is there something that I need to do to configure the (Ubuntu) user `www-data` to access postgres with its own environments variables?

Anyone have an idea of what is going on here?

Comment: Until someone who has experience with Vultr, nginx, ubuntu reads this, I googled Vultr and that's a service where you deploy your app, so my question is have you created PostgreSQL with their service and are you connecting to this Database, did you modified yours `printenv` to the values that they have created for you?

Comment: To your question @Aleksandar, PostgreSQL has been downloaded in the Ubuntu instance with the Linux command `sudo apt install postgresql postgresql-contrib -y`, after ssh'ing in. In other words, Vultr is just my host for the Ubuntu server; as far as know Vultr controls traffic over the ports (like 22 for email) but does not control much else, leaving server configuration up to user (myself in this case.) I just don't know what has to be done to a fresh install of Ubuntu to get it to work with postgres, express.js, and nginx... beyond what I have tried

Answer (score 0):

I found a programmatic solution (without using environment variables) by adding the following to my app:

```
    const pool = new Pool({
        user: 'ubuntu',
        host: 'localhost',
        database: 'testdb',
        password: 'password',
        port: 5432,
    });
```

But I don't yet understand why node-postgres works fine with environment variables in one case and does not in the other, where everything is the same as far as I can tell.

This does not work:

```
    const pool = new Pool({
        user: process.env.PGUSER,
        host: process.env.PGHOST,
        database: process.env.PGDATABASE,
        password: process.env.PGPASSWORD,
        port: process.env.PGPORT, 
    });
```

Anyone have a better solution that allows for environment variables?